# How to make an element with padding only span 100% of the viewport height?

Tags: css, padding, viewport

I'm using a CSS class that sets the height to the full viewport height using:

```css
.fullheight { min-height: 100vh }
```

However, there is a nav bar on the top of my page, and I want to preserve space for it using padding

```css
.padding { padding-top: 55px }
```

Now, I format my div like this:

```html
<div class="fullheight padding"> </div>
```

The padding works fine, but the height of the div of course is now `55px` bigger than my viewport. Since I use different paddings (depending on the shape of the nav bar), I'm looking for a solution that keeps the total height of the div at `100vh`, regardless of the padding I add using an additional class. Possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `box-sizing: border-box` to include padding in the total height of the div. So your code will look like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="fullheight padding"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
.fullheight {
  min-height:         55px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing:     border-box;
  -o-box-sizing:      border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}

.padding {
  padding-top: 55px;
}
```